# Why does Long.MaxValue fit in a Double but < Long.MaxValue not

Tags: scala

I know there is a simple answer for this but it has me puzzled.

Why is it that Long.MaxValue can be stored in a Double and returned as longValue, but a lesser Long loses precision.

I would have expected a loss of precision after 53 bits ? What is going on here

```
scala> val x:Double = Long.MaxValue  // x: Double = 9.223372036854776E18    (9223372036854775807)
scala> x == Long.MaxValue            // Boolean = true
scala> x.longValue == Long.MaxValue  // Boolean = true
scala> val y = 1234567890123456789L  // y: Long = 1234567890123456789  // less than Long.MaxValue
scala> y < x                         // Boolean = true
scala> val z:Double = y              // z: Double = 1.23456789012345677E18
scala> z == y                        // Boolean = true
scala> z.longValue == y              // Boolean = false  // why ? MaxValue fits in the Double
scala> z.longValue                   // 1234567890123456768 <-- loss of 21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually *not* fitting, and it *is* losing precision.

But the loss is because it's being rounded up:

```
scala> BigDecimal.exact(Long.MaxValue.toDouble)
res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 9223372036854775808

scala> Long.MaxValue
res1: Long = 9223372036854775807
```

What happens when you try to fit a too-big `Double` into a `Long`?

```
scala> 1e100.toLong
res2: Long = 9223372036854775807
```

It's truncated.

So `Long.MaxValue` is rounded up to `2^63` which can be represented exactly with 53 bits and a binary exponent, and since it's bigger than `Long.MaxValue` it turns back into `Long.MaxValue` when you convert to `Long`.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a matter of "fitting".  Doubles are just [inherently inexact](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Floating_point#/Accuracy_problems).  Some values will be represented exactly, some won't.  It looks like you found one that can be (your `x`) and one that can't (`y`).

It's not particular to the values you've chosen.  Here's similar behavior with smaller values that clearly "fit" into Doubles:

```
val a = 1.1        // a: Double = 1.1
a == 1.1           // true

val b = 2.2        // b: Double = 2.2
b == 2.2           // true

val c = 1.1 + 2.2  // c: Double = 3.3000000000000003
c == 3.3           // false
```